# Does app engine have a Deploy Hook or Event?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I want to increase the version number on a model whenever there is a new deployment to the server.
So the idea behind this is: Everytime there is a deployment I wanna run some code.

Is this possible within App Engine using hooks or events?

I'm using App Engine for Python.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.

However, you could get the desired behavior if you write your own deployment script.  This script could be a thin wrapper around `appcfg.py` which makes a request to your app once the deployment is complete (the request handler can execute the logic you wanted to put in your "deploy hook").

Comment: Ok thanks. I think I will do try some other method to get the desired result.

Comment: @SamStoelinga did you achieve your desired result with some other method?

Comment: @TheRedPea I don't think I did or I forgot if I did. This was ~7 years ago and I don't even remember why I asked this question nor what I was working on lol.