# Google App Engine - run task on publish

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I have been looking for a solution for my app that does not seem to be directly discussed anywhere. My goal is to publish an app and have it reach out, automatically, to a server I am working with. This just needs to be a simple Post. I have everything working fine, and am currently solving this problem with a cron job, but it is not quite sufficient - I would like the job to execute automatically once the app has been published, not after a minute (or whichever the specified time it may be set to).

In concept I am trying to have my app register itself with my server and to do this I'd like for it to run once on publish and never be ran again.

Is there a solution to this problem? I have looked at Task Queues and am unsure if it is what I am looking for.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: By "publish" do you mean when you deploy a new version of the app, and only then? If a new instance of your app spins up, should it cause a POST request? If you only want it to happen when you publish a new version of the app, I would call that a "deploy hook," like this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4354647

Comment: The desired behavior is only when a new version of the app has been deployed. I suppose 'deploy hook' is the terminology that could be used to discuss this. I will investigate this thread and if I come to a solution I will post that back here. Otherwise just assume I am still working through it.

Answer (score 2):

Personally, this makes more sense to me as a responsibility of your deploy process, rather than of the app itself. If you have your own deploy script, add the post request there (after a successful deploy). If you use google's command line tools, you could wrap that in a script. If you use a 3rd party tool for something like continuous integration, they probably have deploy hooks you could use for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

The main question will be how to ensure it only runs once for a particular version.

Here is an outline on how you might approach it.

You create a HasRun module, which you use store each the version of the deployed app and this indicates if the one time code has been run.

Then make sure you increment your version, when ever you deploy your new code.

In you warmup handler or appengine_config.py grab the version deployed,

then in a transaction try and fetch the new HasRun entity by Key (version number).

If you get the Entity then don't run the one time code.
If you can not find it then create it and run the one time code, either in a task (make sure the process is idempotent, as tasks can be retried) or in the warmup/front facing request.

Now you will probably want to wrap all of that in  memcache CAS operation to provide a lock or some sort. To prevent some other instance trying to do the same thing.

Alternately if you want to use the task queue, consider naming the task the version number, you can only submit a task with a particular name once.
It still needs to be idempotent (again could be scheduled to retry) but there will only ever be one task scheduled for that version - at least for a few weeks.

Or a combination/variation of all of the above.